# Snakemake - set final output filename from configuration

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I'm working on a Snakemake pipeline to extract a list of variants from individual VCF files, then merge them into a single, aggregated (i.e., multi-sample) VCF file.

Here is a toy implementation:

**config.yml**:

```
---
variants_file: "input/variants_all_grch38.tsv"
wgs_file: "input/wgs_gvcf_files_summary_data.tsv"
```

**Snakefile**:

```
configfile: "config.yml"

import pandas as pd

# Returns concatenated single-string output of all variants from input file, e.g., loci = "1:12345,2:34567,3:45678"
def get_loci(variants_tsv: str) -> str:
    variants = pd.read_table(variants_tsv, sep="\t")
    variants = variants.sort_values(["chr", "pos"], ascending=True)[["chr", "pos"]]
    loci = ",".join(variants.astype(str).agg(":".join, axis=1))
    return loci

# Returns multiple lists containing "parts" of equal length, to construct complete file path to VCFs
# e.g.
# part1 = ["p1_v1", "p1_v2", "p1_v3", ...]
# part2 = ["p2_v1", "p2_v2", "p2_v3", ...]
# part3 = ["p3_v1", "p3_v2", "p3_v3", ...]
def get_wgs_parts(wgs_gvcf_paths_data_tsv: str) -> tuple[list[str], list[str], list[str]]:
    wgs_parts_cols = [col1, col2, col3]
    wgs_gvcf_paths_data = pd.read_table(wgs_gvcf_paths_data_tsv, sep="\t")
    wgs_gvcf_paths_data = wgs_gvcf_paths_data.loc[(col4 == "X") & (col5 == "Y")][wgs_parts_cols]
    part1, part2, part3 = tuple(wgs_gvcf_paths_data.T.values.tolist())
    return part1, part2, part3

LOCI = get_loci(config["variants_file"])
PART1, PART2, PART3 = get_wgs_parts(config["wgs_file"])

rule extract_loci:
    input:
        vcf="/path/to/wgs/data/{part1}/{part2}/{part3}.vcf.gz",
        idx="/path/to/wgs/data/{part1}/{part2}/{part3}.vcf.gz.tbi"
    output:
        vcf=temp("output/extracted/{part1}/{part2}/{part3}.vcf.gz"),
        idx=temp("output/extracted/{part1}/{part2}/{part3}.vcf.gz.tbi")
    params:
        loci=LOCI
    shell:
        "bcftools filter -r '{params.loci}' {input.vcf} -Oz -o {output.vcf} && "
        "tabix -p vcf {output.vcf}"

rule merge_vcfs:
    input:
        vcf=expand("output/extracted/{part1}/{part2}/{part3}.vcf.gz", zip, part1=PART1, part2=PART2, part3=PART3),
        idx=expand("output/extracted/{part1}/{part2}/{part3}.vcf.gz.tbi", zip, part1=PART1, part2=PART2, part3=PART3)
    output:
        vcf="output/merged/all_variants.vcf.gz",
        idx="output/merged/all_variants.vcf.gz.tbi"
    shell:
        "bcftools merge {input.vcf} | bcftools sort -T /tmp/ -Oz -o {output.vcf} && "
        "tabix -p vcf {output.vcf}"

# I've deliberately avoided using glob_wildcards()
rule all:
    input:
        vcf=expand("/path/to/wgs/data/{part1}/{part2}/{part3}.vcf.gz", zip, part1=PART1, part2=PART2, part3=PART3),
        idx=expand("/path/to/wgs/data/{part1}/{part2}/{part3}.vcf.gz.tbi", zip, part1=PART1, part2=PART2, part3=PART3)
    output:
        vcf="output/merged/all_variants.vcf.gz",
        idx="output/merged/all_variants.vcf.gz.tbi"
```

I run this pipeline using `snakemake --cores 4 "output/merged/all_variants.vcf.gz"`, & it works correctly.

I'd like to maintain separate aggregated VCFs based on changes I make to the input files (I might change the list of variants to extract, or use a different list of individual VCFs), possibly by having Snakemake use the config file to set the final filename.

I tried adding a new variable in **config.yml** to control this:

**config.yml**

```
variants_file: "input/variants_list1_grch38.tsv"
wgs_file: "input/wgs_gvcf_files_summary_data.tsv"
output_filename: "list1_grch38"
```

**Snakefile**

```
<<truncated>>

rule merge_vcfs:
    input:
        <<truncated>>
    output:
        vcf="output/merged/{output_filename}.vcf.gz",
        idx="output/merged/{output_filename}.vcf.gz.tbi"
    params:
        output_filename=config["output_filename"]
    shell:
        <<truncated>>

rule all:
    input:
        <<truncated>>
    output:
        vcf="output/merged/{output_filename}.vcf.gz",
        idx="output/merged/{output_filename}.vcf.gz.tbi"
    params:
        output_filename=config["output_filename"]
```

I was expecting that after multiple runs (with different input files) of `snakemake --cores 4`, I'd have something like this:

```
$ find $(pwd)
config.yml
input/
input/variants_list1_grch38.tsv
input/variants_list2_grch38.tsv
input/variants_list3_grch37.tsv
input/wgs_gvcf_files_summary_data.tsv
output/
output/merged/
output/merged/list1_grch38.vcf.gz
output/merged/list1_grch38.vcf.gz.tbi
output/merged/list2_grch38.vcf.gz
output/merged/list2_grch38.vcf.gz.tbi
output/merged/list3_grch37.vcf.gz
output/merged/list3_grch37.vcf.gz.tbi
Snakefile
```

However, the dry-run throws this error:

```
WorkflowError:
Target rules may not contain wildcards. Please specify concrete files or a rule without wildcards at the command line, or have a rule without wildcards at the very top of your workflow (e.g. the typical "rule all" which just collects all results you want to generate in the end).
```

Since the final output filename "all_variants" is hardcoded, I can't differentiate between multiple runs of the pipeline.

I'm essentially looking for a way to tell Snakemake to take the final output filename from **config.yml** (or some other configurable means), & allow me to simply run `snakemake --cores 4`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use entries from your `configfile` as output for your `rule all`:

```py
configfile: "config.yml"

rule all:
    input:
        <<truncated>>
    output:
        vcf=expand("output/merged/{output_filename}.vcf.gz", output_filename=config["output_filename"]),
        idx=expand("output/merged/{output_filename}.vcf.gz.tbi", output_filename=config["output_filename"])
    params:
        output_filename=config["output_filename"]
```

The reason your code is currently not working is: You don't expand the wildcard for `output`. Simply providing it to the rule as `param` is not enough

Comment: The explanation of why it didn't work before helped very much, I was able to get this working after I added the config value to the expansion in output(). Thank you very much!